# SELinux - blocks postfix emails sending out from the Web Application

Tags: centos, postfix, selinux

My System environment, is Centos-7.9, Apache2.4, Php-fpm, PHP-7.4

I have postfix setup to send emails from the website, which is working in stand-alone test emails and when I turn the SELinux off.

However, if SELinux is enabled it will block sending the emails out from the server with below error in the
**/var/log/maillog**

```
 postfix/sendmail[10883]: fatal: execv /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: Permission denied
```

When i do

```
  sudo setenforce 0
```

It sends emails, however, I don't want to turn SELinux off, But i would like to allow my Web-Application to white-list sending emails. I tried below but that didn't work

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with RHEL 7.7 an up when using `php-fpm` instead of Apache's `mod_php`. Since you're on CentOS 7.9 it applies.

You can read more regarding the issue on Red Hat's Bugzilla: http://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1754622

As for a solution for your issue, the first and most obvious one is disabling SELinux, but as a second option, I would recommend the following:

1. Install the package `policycoreutils-python`
2. Use `audit2why` and `audit2allow` to create custom rules to enable `php-fpm` to work with SELinux enabled.
3. `tail -f` on `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and try to send a mail message from `httpd`. Get the output and seed it through `audit2why` and `audit2allow`. It would be self explanatory.
4. Apply the rules advised by both programs.

A third solution would be putting `httpd_t` or `system_mail_t` (depending on the output of `audit2allow`) in permissive mode if you don't want to craft custom rules specific to this machine. But keep in mind that doing this you'll be disabling SELinux to an entire context.

That would be done with the following command: `semanage permissive -a httpd_t` or `semanage permissive -a system_mail_t`. To undo the changes just change `-a` to `-d`.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do here is

Put SELinux in permissive mode

```
setenforce 0
```

Rotate the auditd logs so I get a clean(er) list of AVC denials

```
kill -USR1 $(cat /run/auditd.pid)
```

Cause The issue to occur and generate audit messages

Create a local policy module

```
grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m mypolicy >mypolicy.te
```

Check that the generated policy file looks like I expect it to and doesn't 'give away' things I don;t want it to and edit as required.

Create and install the policy

```
checkmodule -M -m -o mypolicy.mod mypolicy.te
semodule_package -o mypolicy.pp -m mypolicy.mod
semodule -i mypolicy.pp
```

You may find it easier to put all the AVC denials into a separate file and then remove the ones that don't relate to the issue you are trying to solve before using audit2alow on the file. If that works better for you you can skip the intermediate steps and go straight to the .pp file

```
cat myavcs.log | audit2allow -M mypolicy
```